# Correct way to implement an iterator to an abstract producer with reference semantics

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, iterator, generator

I have a class that produces values, with an interface like this:

```
template<class T>
class Generator
{
public:
    void advance();
    T* get();
    bool done();
    //...
};
```

The `advance` function advances the producer and places a pointer to the new value in internal storage. The `get` function returns this pointer, or `nullptr` if the `Generator` is done (although the `Generator` can produce `nullptrs` in the course of normal operation, as well). `done` returns true if the `Producer` is done producing values. `get` returns a pointer to allow the client to interact with the produced value, potentially communicating information back to the `Generator`.

This seemed like it'd be very straightforward to implement an iterator for. The `Generator` class isn't copyable, so it itself can't be an iterator, so I created a simple wrapper with the nessesary operations. The problem I've run into is the post-increment operator; advancing the `Generator` invalidates the old pointer. I've played around with different ideas, but none allow me to meet all the requirements for an Input Iterator or Output Iterator. I don't want my iterators to have a copy of the value, because I'd like to have reference semantics through the pointer. The closest I've come is to have the iterators store a increment counter, and only advance the `Generator` on a dereference or comparison operation. This inloves a `const_cast` and besides feel very dangerous. Is there any way to implement a correct iterator for this interface?

Comment: Do I get you right: having a valid iterator i; another iterator j = i; and ++j invalidates i !?

Comment: At any rate, `i == j` doesn't (can't) imply `++i == ++j`, so he's limited to input iterators.

Comment: Invalidates it for dereference, yes. This is normal behavior allowed by the [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) concept. The problem is that, while old invalidating old iterators is fine, *it++ is still supposed to work.

Comment: (void)r++ and *r++ are required for input iterators - a slight difference

Comment: I fear you have to move your object in post-increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, I think the best you can do is an input
iterator.  One of the guarantees of forward iterators are that
they are multipass, and I don't see how you can do this with
your class.  Your class doesn't support memorizing a position,
and restarting from it, so once one iterator has advanced, none
of the others can ever see that element.

Of course, there's still a number of things you can do with an
input iterator, but if they are not sufficient, you'll have to
use the iterator to copy the values into a vector, and iterate
over that.

EDIT:

Concerning your comment about the necessity of `*r++` working:
I think that the following would be legal:

```
template <typename T>
class GeneratorIterator
{
    class PostIncrProxy
    {
        GeneratorIterator* myOwner;
    public:
        PostIncrProxy( GeneratorIterator* owner )
            : myOwner( owner )
        {
        }
        ~PostIncrProxy()
        {
            ++(*myOwner);
        }
        T* operator*() const
        {
            return **myOwner;
        }
    };

    Generator<T>* myOwner;
public:
    GeneratorIterator( Generator<T>& owner )
        : myOwner( &owner )
    {
    }
    GeneratorIterator()           //  End iterator...
        : myOwner( nullptr )
    {
    }

    bool operator==( GeneratorIterator const& other ) const
    {
        return (myOwner == nullptr) == (other.myOwner == nullptr);
    }
    bool operator!=( GeneratorIterator const& other ) const
    {
        return !operator==( other );
    }

    T* operator*() const
    {
        assert( myOwner != nullptr );
        return myOwner->get();
    }
    //  -> not necessary if we're iterating over T*.  If 

    GeneratorIterator& operator++()
    {
        assert( myOwner != nullptr );
        myOwner->advance();
        if ( myOwner->done() ) {
            myOwner = nullptr;
        }
    }

    PostIncrProxy operator++(int)
    {
        return PostIncrProxy( this );
    }
};
```

This will defer the actual incrementation until the end of the
full expression, which I suppose could be a problem in some
degenerate cases, but I'd at least give it a try.  (If worse
comes to worst, you could also do the increment in the
`PostIncrProxy::operator*`, once you'd recovered the return
value, and then set its `myOwner` to null, testing for the case
in the destructor.)

Comment: The problem is that even lowly `InputIterator`s require `auto x = *it++` to work.

Comment: @Lucretiel Yes, but that's not really very difficult.  The classical solution is to keep a copy of the value in the iterator (like `istream_iterator`), but you can probably work around that by having `it++` return a proxy, which handles the `*` correctly, and does the actual incrementation in its destructor.  (I think that this is actually conformant; it would explain why the standard specifies `*r++`, and not just `*a` and `r++` in table 107.)

Comment: @Lucretiel I've just edited my answer with a rough sketch of what I had in mind.  I think it's conform, but I'm not sure that the standard is clear on this point.

Comment: It turns out I needn't have worried. I'm implementing this iterator with boost::iterator_facade, and they take care of proxying it for you.